# User-defined slots for menu pyqt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots

According to what I know, `Qt Designer` is unable to work with signal/slot handling(a slot defined by me). Do you have documentation for `user-defined slots` for menus?

1. I use PyQt
2. Other widgets are able to define user-defined slots

**Question:** How can I define my own slot for a menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to make user-defined slots for menus in Qt, something like this should work:

Add a `QAction` to the menu item, and connect the action's `triggered` signal to a slot.

```
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        testAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('test.png'), '&Exit', self)
        testAction.triggered.connect(self.runExample)
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        testMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Test')
        testMenu.addAction(testAction)

    def runExample(self):
        print "Running example."
```